# Find the 25-th percentile of Exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A random variable X can be modeled by the Exponential distribution, where β=4.

Find the 25-th percentile, X25.

I have tried taking the natural log and solving an equation akin to this: e^x/4 = 0.25 Solving for x I get 12.88.

Of course this is not correct. I am curious as to how to find the 25th percentile of X.

Comment: Parentheses,** please**.  When you write e^x/4 do you mean $\frac {e^x}4$ or $e^{(x/4)}$?  Neither one gives anything close to $x \approx 12.88$, so please show your work and we can find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $q^{\rm th}$ quantile of a random variable $X$ is the value $x$ such that $$\Pr[X \le x] = q.$$  So in your case $q = 0.25$, and $$0.25 = \Pr[X \le x] = F_X(x) = 1 - e^{-x/\beta}.$$  This gives us $e^{-x/4} = 0.75$, or $$x = - 4 \log 0.75 \approx 1.15073.$$  This assumes that the parametrization of the exponential distribution is by scale; i.e., if $\beta = 4$ this means $\operatorname{E}[X] = \beta = 4$, rather than by rate--in which case $\operatorname{E}[X] = 1/\beta = 1/4$.

Comment: your answer should say -4ln(0.75) as it pertains to the natural logarithm, otherwise thank you.

Comment: @sawreals2 It is customary in higher mathematics (as opposed to, for example, high school mathematics) to write $\log$ to indicate the natural logarithm, because $e$ is the only logarithmic base that is of interest.  You are welcome to use $\ln$ but my usage of $\log$ is quite deliberate, and it is understood among pure mathematicians what is meant.